# handling different XML versions in REST application

Tags: xml, rest, jaxb

I am developing a RESTful web service. I want to support client using older XML schema versions. What is the best way to maintain different schema on server side. 
1. I am using Etag to compare old (object present in server side) and new (object coming from server) object.
2. I want to send (marshal) xml for client schema version (for which the request came)